# Fitting Data to Model Equation

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

I am attempting to fit an equation which models how fast a chemical reaction progresses. Given the following equation:

$$\ln(k)= \ln\biggl(\frac{d\,k_0\,M}{1+P_r}\biggl)+\ln\biggl(\frac{a\exp(-b/T)+\exp(-T/c)}{1+s\ln^2(P_r)}\biggl)+e\,\ln T$$

where
$$k_0=f\,T^g \exp\biggl(\frac{-h}{R\,T}\biggl)$$
and
$$P_r=M\,\frac{f}{i}\,T^{g-j}\exp⁡\biggl(\frac{k-h}{R\,T}\biggl)$$

The variables I would like to fit are $a-k$. $M$ is a function determined outside of this regression; $s$ is a non-fit constant. I already have the derivatives and can perform a standard curve fit/least squares fit; however, I don't have a method of finding a good initial guess. Since this will be in an optimization scheme, the values of $\ln(k)$ will vary and the prior guess will not always be sufficient. I've found [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028141/fitting-data-that-follows-specific-equation/4029070#4029070) [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306953/sum-of-exponential-growth-and-decay) with answers by @JJacquelin, but I'm uncertain how to implement this method with my equation. An English translation to the scribd papers that JJacquelin refers to can be found [here](https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendices/reei/translation.html#).

Sample data is given as
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
T& M & \ln(k) \\ \hline
1513.8 & 7.95\times10^{-9} & -1.0378 \\ \hline
1889.7 & 6.36\times10^{-9} & 5.3839 \\ \hline
2513.8 & 4.78\times10^{-9} & 9.4501 \\ \hline
1513.8 & 7.95\times10^{2} & -0.6490 \\ \hline
1889.7 & 6.36\times10^{2} & 6.7692 \\ \hline
2513.8 & 4.78\times10^{2} & 13.6235 \\ \hline
1513.8 & 5.30\times10^{-3} & -0.7416 \\ \hline
1763.8 & 4.55\times10^{-3} & 4.2598 \\ \hline
2013.8 & 3.98\times10^{-3} & 7.5729 \\ \hline
2263.8 & 3.54\times10^{-3} & 9.8066 \\ \hline
2513.8 & 3.19\times10^{-3} & 11.3176 \\ \hline
\end{array}

and $s=0.1886$

Edit: A few additional notes.

1. Fitting $a-k$ may have been too ambitious and unnecessary. What if instead I only fit $a-e$?
2. The number of data points being kept small is intentional. I use the minimum number of $\ln k$ to define the constants; however, I think I can have as many as 11 values define 5 variables if I instead only fit $a-e$.
3. The data that I am working with is numerical. It has machine precision and does not have uncertainty.

Comment: have you tried to study the convexity of your problem ? it could help you figure out how your initial guess matters

Comment: NHL - I have not derived the Hessian for this, but I can say that putting in different initial guesses will result in different answers in my least squares solution.

Comment: That is a lot of constants to evaluate, which means you need much more and very accurate data.  Do you really know $T$ (is it temperature?) to five places?

Comment: Ross - Yes, it is a lot of constants. The phenomena that this models can be more complex than these constants can describe, so this is actually a compromise. I've reduced the equations, but this refers to the SRI formulation here https://cantera.org/science/reactions.html#falloff-reactions.

You are correct that T is temperature. In this case T, M and ln(k) are determined numerically so they have machine precision.

Comment: The method you mentioned transforms a non-linear to a linear problem of regression thanks to a convenient integral equation. Unfortunately the function to fit is much too complicated. One cannot expect to find an integral equation involving not too many numerical integrations. Moreover the data is too small to proceed to multiple numerical integrations without large deviations. Sorry, I think that this method is not recommended in your case.

Comment: @JJacquelin - Would the transformation become possible if I only tried to do a regression for a - e? k0 and Pr would become known variables like M. This would be 11 data points for 5 fit constants. I know it's not ideal, but I hope that it might be enough?

Comment: @TSikes. Unfortunately not. Also the function $T(M,k)$ is slightly simpler, but much too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

For this sort of regression problem, one of the standard algorithms for non-linear least squares is the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm. As far as the initial guess, you could just use the regressed parameters of a similar reaction system or the last set of parameters.

In your case, with models that are somewhat parsimonious you can add regularization to the parameters to tame some of the problems with it, I think nonlinear ridge regression would help in this case. However, with such a nonlinear model with datapoints = the number of regressed variables you will have many cases of regressed models just being nonsense.

As a side note from someone who has regressed reaction parameters from data, you can't really trust them more than $\approx \pm 10\%$. Unless you are running this as a simulation, an appropriate error bar on this data set would be in the neighborhood of $1\%$ relative error for every reading (for reasonable well-maintained gauges and sensors).

Comment: I've already tried bounded and unbounded curve fitting such as LM. Since the system is not convex, the initial guesses matter. I am searching for a method to get better initial guesses. Relying on prior guesses is also not possible in my application. In my curve fitting I already scale my fit constants based upon the gradient. I'll look into ridge regression.

I added a note in the post to clarify that this data is numerical.